# why can't I use getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() to create a folder on my SD card and store photos in it?

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

I got a FileNotFoundException@5818 when I try to get a file address using getExternalStoragePublicDirectory().

This is my method copied from [Google Dev Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#PublicFiles):

```
public File getPublicDir(String albumName) {
// Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
if (!file.mkdirs()) {
    Log.e("PUBLIC DIRECTORY", "Directory not created");
}
return file;
}
```

I call this method here:

```
try{
 FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(getPublicDir("mySnapshot"));
 Boolean success=snapshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Compress? 
  :"+success,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 fos.close();
}catch(IOException e){
 e.printStackTrace();
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"NOT SAVED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**I am not exactly sure what albumName is. Is it the name of the folder to be created or the name of the photo file to be stored?**

Here is a screenshot of the error it throws when I was debugging:

[image]

It throws the error at line "FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(getPublicDir("mySnapshot"));."

Write permission added.

Here is what my app looks like (GIF), and the error it throws:

[image]

This is where I create a folder (GIF):\

[image]

I found [here](https://www.journaldev.com/9400/android-external-storage-read-write-save-file) a way to write text into directory, it works but it's only for text:

```
try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myExternalFile);
                fos.write(inputText.getText().toString().getBytes());
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

myExternalFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), filename);
private String filename = "SampleFile.txt";
private String filepath = "MyFileStorage";
```

Comment: Your error msg says permission denied. Have added permissions to manifest for read write

Comment: Yeah I did I added the write permission.

Comment: Have you made runtime permission check?

Comment: how do I do that? can you link me to a tutorial? I think it's really complicated. You have first check the SDK version and make the dialog requesting user permission.

Comment: If you are targeting >23, which is a must from the end of the month, you should ask runtime permissions. There is hundreds of tutorials online on how to achieve this.

Comment: For testing purposes, you can grant the permissions manually from Settings > Apps > YourApp > Permissions.

Comment: great question Joe, I see you did a lot of research.